# How can we develop a parental control app on iOS using mdm if we are not a company suitable for enterprise (over 100 employees)?

Tags: ios, mdm, parental-control

We're developing a parental app control (we already have it on Android devices) and want to extend it to iOS users. The app works monitoring device usage, so we need info of installed apps, time spent on apps, time spent on device, filtering by days and time, etc.

We've read that this could be done through mdm program (not screen time API, since Screen Time API its integrated on device parental control and doesn't allow us to manage child device information and monitor from parent device (weather it's Android or iPhone).

The problem is that mdm program requires a enterprise developer enrollment, and we are a legal company, but not over 100 employees. We contacted support and they said we cannot apply for it, and sent to us some info about Business program and School program, which is not suitable for us since we don't need the distribution part of mdm program, we need the device monitoring part of mdm.

Any help on this? Really apple doesn't let small companies to develop this kind of apps?

We are trying to be able to use Apple mdm, enrolling on enterprise program... but they said we are not allowed since our company is < 100 employees.

Comment: You cannot develop an MDM solution without an enterprise program membership.  You need to generate a certificate that can only be done with an enterprise program.

Comment: @Paulw11 and its impossible to enroll on enterprise if we are below 100 employees as they said? even contacting support?

Comment: I would imagine so, but only Apple can answer that question

Comment: I may be possible through https://business.apple.com/ which is not limited to +100 companies but I am not sure you will have access to such data